# Implement a custom split view for iPad (OpenGL + controls)

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, ipad

I'm new to iOS development and I would like my app main screen to be divided horizontally in 2 views: the top view would display an OpenGL render and the bottom one would display some controls which affect the top view. Currently, I have my OpenGL view implemented and filling up the full screen. 
Does anybody know a good tutorial on the best way to do that?
I've spent some time looking on the web but I'm probably not using the right terms because I haven't found any relevant tutorial or code example.

I believe The Split View Controller is not what I'm looking for because it looks like it requires one of the view to be a table and the views to have some kind of master/detail relationship.

Thanks for any pointer!

Steven

Comment: For future reference, you might have better luck tagging this sort of question [tag:OpenGL-ES]. [tag:OpenGL] has higher viewership, but [tag:OpenGL-ES] has the sort of specialized crowd that just might know what you're talking about; you are dealing with OpenGL ES on iOS after all.

Comment: Did you find anything?

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL backed views can be used almost exactly like any other UIView.

Simply modify the OpenGL view's frame either in interface builder or in code to fill the part of the screen you want, then add another subview to the main view controller (either in IB or in code) that fills the other part of the view.

Comment: True dat. If you're not using [view controller containment](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6) you won't be able to use a `GLKViewController` to manage animation of the `GLKView`'s contents, but there's nothing wrong with making your own `CADisplayLink` timer that calls the `GLKView`'s `display` method.